# Terraform module to create AWS SNS Topic Subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am not able to find terraform module to create AWS SNS Topic subscription. e.g: I used "terraform-aws-modules/sns/aws" to create SNS topic. Can someone point me to source module for subscription?

Comment: Why do you want a module for this? What's wrong with just using the resource?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I needed a module as I have to reuse it. Anyways, I have created a new module which is working fine.

Answer (score 8):

You should prefer resources to modules unless you have a complex use case involving many interacting resources in a common pattern.

Modules are best suited to standardizing common patterns. A module can be made for a single resource, but it's rarely worth the overhead.

Here is a worked example based on a real system. This creates an SNS topic and subscribes a Lambda function to it:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "kpis" {
  name = var.sns_topic_name
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "invoke_with_sns" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.kpis.arn
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = module.kpis.function_arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_sns_invoke" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSNS"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = module.lambda.function_name
  principal     = "sns.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_sns_topic.kpis.arn
}
```

You can read more about **aws_sns_topic_subscription** here:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_subscription

Comment: Thanks Alain for the details. I needed module so that I can re-use it create similar resources in my project. I created a one and it is working fine.

Comment: Updated terraform link: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_subscription